# Is it possible to deploy an app in Google Cloud Platform that is only accessible at certain locations?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops

I'm currently working on an assignment, where I'm building a high-level architecture on Google Cloud Platform, to which I'm completely new.

The assignment is about building a new system in which it's possible to have standardized testing across all schools in the state. One of the requirements are that student can only use the application (school test application) within designated testing centers, which will mostly be schools.

I've tried looking it up, but since this question is rather specific, I'm unsure about my findings. My own thoughts are that I have to note that the app is only accessible from approved "testing centers".

*My main objective is to get school test data from this/these app(s).*

**Question:**
My question is then if it's "normal practice" to deploy an app, which is only accessible from certain geographical locations or if the requirement is there to confuse/trick me?

**EDIT:** The first part of the assignment:

*A large state would like a new system to support standardized testing across all public school systems. The system should be able to handle 40,000+ students, 2000 teachers and 50 administrators.*

Requirements:

- Students will only be able to use the application within testing centers around the state, most of these will be in the schools, but not all of them
- Students should be able to take a test, and the results eventually
  consolidated to a single location representing all of the test scores
  across the state (by school, teacher, and student).

Comment: Not unusual, and whitelisting certain IP ranges would probably be your best bet.

Comment: @ceejayoz So as an example, there could be multiple test center location which are whitelisted for this app, along with some sort of local database which stores the local app data?

Comment: Why a local database? IP restrictions don't require you to add the complexity that'd entail.

Comment: @ceejayoz I just assumed that since there is a geographical requirement in the assignment and that the assignment is about data (engineering) and not directly applications.

Comment: What might the options be on the sources of authorized requests?  For example, only from authorized IP addresses?  Do we have the ability to install special software on the machines such as non-exportable certificates?   One robust mechanism is to require all machines that access the application to have a physical security key present (https://cloud.google.com/security-key).

Comment: @Kolban The options are pretty open, as I just have to assume and argument my way out of it. However, I’m not looking for the most complicated solution.

Comment: Gotcha ... the answers seem to be splitting on whether you need geographical knowledge of the source of the request.  For example, a named city, state or country.  I had been assuming that your requirement was the applications had to be accessed from a finite set of identified machines or from any machines in an identified facility (which would have an identifiable IP address range).  I was wondering if we could clarify these notions.

Comment: @Kolban I've added the first part of the assignment for clarification. Again, the question is really open, so I'm looking for a best-practice in mentioned cases.

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing sounds exactly like the sweet spot for the Google product called Identity-Aware Proxy ... see the following:

https://cloud.google.com/iap

This can provide a proxy to your apps which validates that the callers have the correct identity *and* context.  From your description, it seems like *context* is the key concept.  This will allow/deny access based on context such as:

- device security status
- IP address

See also:

- [How Airbnb Secured Access to Their Cloud With Context-Aware Access (Cloud Next '19)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sq9gp8KBsY0)

Comment: Thank you - I'll look into it. But is this also used for storing application data in some sort of cloud storage? My first thought was that this is more a question about who can access, and not where?

Comment: From the update ... when I read "Students will only be able to use the application within testing centers around the state".  To me, this is protection from access based on location rather than identity.  Imagine an education test ... to prevent cheating, we want to be sure that ONLY students ACTUALLY validated as being present are answering the questions and not the students smarter friends who might be trying to answer on their behalf from home.  I am imaginging that during a test, each student would be given a userid/password/pincode by the proctor and hence identity isn't a core issue.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm just confused by the part "...most of these will be in the schools, but not all of them", thinking that the school could allow students to take tests from home (which is not that unlikely in these times...). But I will just assume that this is not the case here, and "not all of them" simply refers to "not school".

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Platform offers a solution for geo-based location access that is integrated with their [load balancers](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/choosing-load-balancer) called **[Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/understanding-google-cloud-armors-new-waf-capabilities)**.

> There are times when you may need to limit access to an application to certain countries—whether it is for regulatory compliance, copyright licensing, or another business need. With Google Cloud Armor, you can now configure security policies to create allow lists or deny lists based on the country code of the client request attempting to reach your application.

If your application is running behind it, you can just use [country codes (ISO 3166)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2#Current_codes) to **[allow traffic from that region](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference#deny_traffic_from_a_specific_region)** using Google's [Common Expression Language](https://github.com/google/cel-spec):

```
origin.region_code == 'US'
```

Furthermore, you can add other [attributes](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference#attributes) to identify the incoming requests for finer control.

Finally, all your request are also [logged into Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/monitoring) since Cloud Armor is integrated with other IaaS products on GCP.

The main advantage is that this control happens at load balancer level, this implies that you don't need to add any extra logic to your application as all the management is done before the requests hit your app.

As a last thing on technical side: Is not mentioned in your question but if you're using Google App Engine, Cloud Armor is not fully integrated yet. However there is a [feature request with a workaround for that](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70604631#comment2).

**Addressing your explicit question**: *Is then if it's "normal practice" to deploy an app, which is only accessible from certain geographical locations?*

Yes. One example -as mentioned above- sometimes there's a need to limit access based on country-level due to regulatory compliances or as you mentioned: Your application should only be accessible from "approved testing centers" (which can be also done with Cloud Armor if you have a narrower [IP-based access limit](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference#multiple_expressions)).

As a side note on regards on the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62305987/10892354) in this thread (and just for the sake of clarity), Identity Aware Proxy validates the identity of the requester, not where it's coming from.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Great answer. So for additional clarity, IAP only "checks" who the person is, but not where the person is?

Comment: Yes. Its essential function is to validate who is requesting your service rather than from where that request is coming from. There is [a way to use IP addresses to relay requests to GCE instances with IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding), but this is not necessarily a primary feature of the product but specifically covers one identity-related scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the App Engine product I recommend you take a look on the Setting Up Access Control document [1], this is a good practice in order to control who an can access to your instance, also you can check how works the firewall rules for App Engine [2].

Also as is mentioned on the answer of yyyahir, you can check the Cloud Armor product[3] in order to deny the traffic from specific region.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/access-control
[2] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/creating-firewalls
[3] https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference#deny_traffic_from_a_specific_region